# How to find the minimum depth of an object from MS Kinect?

Tags: c++

I'm new to the MS Kinect and I am trying to find the minimum depth from the camera to draw a circle around it for now ? I'm trying to use the samples provided by Microsoft but no luck. I am using visual studio (C++).

Thank you for your help guys.